# Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have successfully hosted an local .NET server with the url: http://localhost:65349/. Now I want to change the "localhost" to my IP Address such that the Web is still running,however, the 400 HTTP error received

I have download the iisexpress-proxy into my computer by Nodejs, however, why trying to run the IIS Proxy file within my.NET project, I receive the error of "Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined" as embedded in the piece of codes below. 
So I want to ask what is the error and how to configure.

```
proxyServer.listen(proxyPort, function() {
  console.log('Listening... [press Control-C to exit]');
}).on('error', function (err, req, res) {
  console.log(err.stack);
  console.log('Listening... [press Control-C to exit]');
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Aw snap! Something went wrong. Check your console to see the error.');
});
```

Here is the image error log:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GidIo.png)

Comment: can you show me log of res and err

Comment: Here are the 2 errors:                                                    
 - listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80                       
 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined

Comment: I have also give the full image log in the questions.

Comment: Anyone know the problems embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but I got this error when I tried to use a port that was already in use as the proxy port.  Using a different available port fixed it.